# Html/css button

Tags: html, css

```
.classname {
background-image:url(../../images/classname.png);
background-color:transparent;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
text-align:center;
border:none;
height:50px;
width:160px;
font-size:12px;
font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
color:#CCC;
}
```

```
<div class="classname">Text</div>
```

Why the Text is above of image? What should I add to make it normal? I can use `padding-top`, but then the bottom of image will have space too if you know what I mean.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I created this for you](http://jsbin.com/asada), I *think* that's how you want to make it.

Answer (score 0):

Because the image is a *background* for the text.

If you're trying to make an image button with text fallback, do `<img src="someurl" alt="sometext" />`

What do you mean by above?

Comment: you should try it yourself and you'll see

Comment: Well based just on the code there, 'above' would mean 'on top of in the z plane', I can read the CSS. Which would imply to me that you want the text to only appear if the image doesn't. In which case my answer should solve your problem.